# Declare a function on an array of unknown type in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

I'd like to write a function on an array, but I'd like to have a generic type.  For argument, let's make it a sum.

```
proc mySum(x:[] int) {
  return + reduce x;
}
proc mySum(x:[] real) {
  return + reduce x;
}
```

What is the notation for a generic type? I thought it was something like `proc mySum(x: [] <T>) {}` but that does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to just leave the element type off in the formal type declaration:

```
proc mySum(x:[]) {
  return + reduce x;
}

writeln(mySum([1, 2, 3]));
writeln(mySum([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]));
```

which will give you:

```
6
6.0
```

If you want to have a way of referring to the type symbolically, you can also use the following syntax to query it and bind it to an identifier (`t` here):

```
proc mySum(x:[] ?t) {
  writeln("I'm computing a reduction over an array of ", t:string);
  return + reduce x;
}

writeln(mySum([1, 2, 3]));
writeln(mySum([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]));
```

which will give you:

```
I'm computing a reduction over an array of int(64)
6
I'm computing a reduction over an array of real(64)
6.0
```

(Of course, you could also do things like declare variables of type `t`, etc.)

Comment: @user3666197 - I think your edit would have been better as a comment, since it brings up a separate topic, that parallel reductions are not deterministic w.r.t. ordering. Also, making stylistic changes is generally frowned upon, especially when it results in inconsistent coding style within the response.

Comment: Neither of the claims is consistent with the original post, or the StackOveflow shared content. If you consider a code read-ability step an adverse for the Community members, you are free to revise the post and make it worse readable ( yet you may consider the StackOverflow content be also educational, so "coding-style" *normatives*, enforced in some large shared-library or corporate projects **are not of a merit here**, the kind **readers ease of understanding is**. That is fair, isn't it? The objection about an ordering in **`+ reduce x`** ops is off topic here, as it works this very way...

Comment: I don't see that adding the reduction over strings, which merely illustrates a bug in the current implementation of Chapel without adding any value w.r.t. the original question, is a meaningful or beneficial change and plan to roll it back or edit it out.

Comment: I'm not saying that the call using an array of strings is illegitimate in any way w.r.t. the generic argument, simply that I do not believe it adds additional value to the original answer while also introducing potential confusion due to a known bug in the implementation of + reductions on strings (namely that it's treated as commutative when it should not be).

If a sample third type was needed, one that is not buggy, such as an array of bools, complexes, or arrays seems preferable. But since the original question asked about two types, answering using those two types also seems sufficient.

Comment: @user3666197: if you wish to build on Brad's answer, the license conditions allow you to copy it and make changes in a new answer, as long as you credit the author.

Comment: @halfer thanks for your remark, it was not my intent to "*build on Brad's answer*" it was my fault to improve the code examples.